# c# загрузка Image файла через datagridview в базу данных

Tags: c#, datagridview

создаю локальное приложение (регистратор писем) есть база данных MySql, туда грузится общие данные, в том числе отсканированные документы, при загрузки Image файла через DataGridview в базу данных через приложение в Datagrid-е вылазит такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот собственно код

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
        string sql = "insert into giris(tb, register_date, register_number, name_organization, description, image) Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "',  '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" +pictureBox1.Text + "')";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("OK");
        
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
        textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
        spisok();
    }

    // открывает файл для загрузки 
    private void buttonbtnLoadPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg; *.png; *.gif)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif";
        
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
         //   pictureBox2pbxPhoto.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
         //   pictureBox2pbxPhoto.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: pictureBox1.Text - что простите?

Comment: гмм, подскажите пожалуйста, как конвертировать ....

Comment: я сначала в pictureBox вставляю потом в Datagrid, подскажите пожалуйста мою ошибку

Comment: Вы показали код, который никак не относится к показанной ошибке.

Comment: Ещё раз: вы показали код, который работает с PictureBox. А ошибка у вас возникает в DataGridView. Покажите тот код, в котором возникает ошибка!

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
strig sql = $"insert into giris(tb, register_date, register_number, name_organization, description, img_bytelength, image) Values (@tb, @register_date, @register_number, @name_organization, @description, @img_bytelength, @image)";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tb", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("register_date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("register_number", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name_organization", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("img_bytelength", img?.Length ?? 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", img);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: благодарю за отклик, все равно  Datagrid ругается ( прежняя ошибка )

Comment: Не используйте метод `AddWithValue`! Используйте перегрузку метода `Add`, принимающую тип данных `MySqlDbType`.

Comment: @jun66 Колонка с изображением в DataGridView должна быть типа DataGridViewImageColumn, а в качестве параметра ячейки .Value должен подаваться Bitmap, а не Image или Byte[] или MemoryStream (и вообще любой Steam)

Comment: Blackmeser, ваш ответ более подходящий , в этом направлении должен копаться ...